# Correcting issues with the "While" loop

Tags: java

I just started with while loops today and I'm currently struggling with a code. I must ask a user to enter a starting and ending value for the while loop. The results should display all the multiples of 4 between the starting and ending value. This is homework so a while loop must be included.

For example, the user enters 1 for the starting value and 4 for the ending value. The code should display 4 * the values in between the starting and ending value). I don't know how to make the numbers in between multiply with 4.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class WhileEx {

public static void main(String[] args){ 

int start = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a starting number (integer)")); 
int end = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an ending number (integer)"));        

while (start < end)
{
    start = start * 4;
    System.out.print (start +  "  ");       
}
}
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific with what you have tried and what is and isn't working?

Comment: Could you provide *some tests*, e.g. what is desired behavior for `start == 1; end == 5`, `start == 1; end == 16`, `start = -1; end = 0`?

Comment: @Win.ubuntu: I doubt: set `start = -1` and `end = 0` and see what you'll get .

Comment: Has nothing to do with the while loop. The logic's wrong, `x=x*4` doesn't give you the multiples of 4.

Comment: you are multiplying (start*4) this will not give you the multiples of 4 between the starting and ending value (for example, between 2 and 13 we have 4,8 and 12, but with your loop we will get 8 and 32 (8*4). It is not a code problem, change ```start=start*4``` for something that actually gives you multiples of 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll give you two hints:

1. What is the first multiple of 4 which is greater than or equal to `start`? Your program should work for cases where `start` is already a multiple of 4 (say, 32) and when it is not (e.g. 29).
2. How do you get from a certain multiple from 4 (say, 32) to the next one (36)?

If instead, you need to

> display 4 * the values in between the starting and ending value

the simplest solution is then:

```
while (start <= end)
{
    System.out.print((start * 4) + " ");
    start = start + 1;
}
```

Comment: yet another hints: what if `start` is *negative*? what if `start` is *zero*?

Comment: Thanks for the help! It's actually very simple I can't believe I haven't figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need the `%`, which returns rest after division.

This is how you can do it, there is solution with simple for cycle and then with while cycle.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int start = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a starting number (integer)"));
    int end = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an ending number (integer)"));

    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        if (i % 4 == 0){
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }

    System.out.println("");

    int i = start + (4 - (start % 4));
    while (i < end){
        System.out.print(i + " ");
        i += 4;
    }
}
```

Output for values 2 and 63 :

```
4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40 44 48 52 56 60 
4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40 44 48 52 56 60
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the mod operator -> %
That would give you the remainder and if it's 0 - you got a multiple of 4.

Example:

```
if(start%4 == 0){
System.out.print (start); 
}
start++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are updating `start` value to its 4xtimes value, in the next iteration of while loop, this new value will be checked, which is not correct. Do not update the same variable which is used in the while condition. Use another variable to multiply by 4 and then use it to display.

**Edit:**
You need to use the increment operator `++` to increase the `start` value to reach the `end`.

Also, your while loop should be like this:

```
int temp=0;
while (start < end)
{
temp = start * 4;
System.out.print (temp +  "  ");       
start++; 
}
```

Better yet:

```
while (start < end)
{
System.out.print ((start * 4) +  "  ");       
start++; 
}
```

@kittykittybangbang: Thanks for suggesting the edit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Along with your explanation, please provide code (our pseudo code) to best answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class WhileEx {

    public static void main(String[] args){ 

    int start = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a     starting number (integer)")); 
    int end = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an ending   number (integer)"));  
    if(start==0 || start%4>0)
    {
        start = start +(4-start%4);
    }
    while (start <= end)
    {
        System.out.print (start +  "  ");       
        start = start + 4;

    }
    }
    }
```